# react-native: borderRadius does not frame component right

Tags: mobile, reactjs, react-native

The `borderRadius` style attribute doesn't change the border of a component correctly.

I would expect to see a green circle on the red background without any white space. Instead, I see this.

[image]

```
class Healthie extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.button} />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});
```

react-native version: 0.17.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get what you're looking for, you're going to have to wrap the Text box inside another View. The View will not default to another BG color when the borderRadius is changed:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.button}>
    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}>Text</Text>
  </View>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 50,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    textAlign: 'center',
    flexDirection:'row', 
    alignItems:'center', 
    justifyContent:'center'
  }
});
```

Check out [this](https://rnplay.org/apps/_JYtmw) demo.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Even without `{{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}`.

Answer (score 22):

no need to wrap button or text inside views, just put this on your style

```
overflow: hidden
```

it works for me

Comment: This works on ios, but not on android. At least as of RN 0.25. The correct answer is the accepted answer.